# Which has lower rate of getting pregnant and/or a venereal dicease in condom vs pill?

Tags: sex, statistics, effectiveness, pill, condom

If you use either a pill or condom to have sex with your partner, what is the probability of getting pregnant and/or getting a venereal dicease in each case?

I wonder which is more effective in terms of the probability.

Is there any research or statistics in this field? I don't mind it by country and age (though it is preferable to filter it), but I would like to restrict it only to heterosexual sex.

Comment: Decease is death.   You do know the pill has no effect on venereal disease?

Comment: @Paparazzi Oh my English sucks. It's disease. But does it have literally NO effect on venereal diseases?

Comment: @Blaszard No effect whatsoever on venereal disease. Birth control pills prevent only pregnancies, not diseases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

The pill *slightly more effective* than condom for contraception. Other methods are better still.

The pill is **ineffective** for preventing STI; condoms are mostly effective.

## In Full

First things first. Statistics on contraception efficacy are widely available, so as a bonus you are getting info on several more types than just 'condom' and 'pill'.

## How effective is contraception at preventing pregnancy?

Reported in percentages; take the percent away from 100 if you would prefer to know how many women in a hundred will fall pregnant *despite using the contraception correctly*.

### Short-Acting

- **male condoms**: 98% (NB *heavily* dependent on effective / proper use)
- **female condom**s: 95%
- diaphragms: 92-96%
- caps: 92-96%
- **COCP** (combined oral contraceptive pill): >99%
- **POP** (progestogen-only pill): 99%

### Long-active Reversible Contraception (LARC)

- contraceptive injection: >99%
- contraceptive implant: >99% (NB: over **three** years)
- IUS (intrauterine system): >99% (NB: over **five** years)
- IUD (intrauterine device): >99%
- contraceptive patch: >99%
- vaginal ring: >99%

### 'Permanent'

- female sterilisation: >99% (1 in 200)
- male sterilisation: > 99% (1 in 2000)

### 'Natural'

- natural family planning: ≤ 99% (ie up to 99%, depending on how closely it is followed)

*(condoms and pills highlighted in bold)*

Source: [NHS contraception guide](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/contraception-guide/Pages/how-effective-contraception.aspx); from which the stats are liberally taken.

**Note**: The [CDC also publishes a poster family planning methods](https://www.cdc.gov/reproductivehealth/unintendedpregnancy/pdf/contraceptive_methods_508.pdf). The percentages are the number of pregnancies per year (ie the opposite of the NHS published statistics). They also give *actual effectiveness*, rather than assuming correct use every time. For **condoms in particular, this means only 82% effectiveness (vs 99%)**; and for **the pill**, 92% (vs >99%). There is [further information available](https://www.cdc.gov/reproductivehealth/contraception/).

Although it isn't an 'accepted' source, there is a [Wikipedia page with a table on contraceptive effectiveness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_birth_control_methods#Effectiveness); the more important part is in the [references section of the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_birth_control_methods#References) which has plenty of further reading.

## How effective are condoms vs the pill for preventing STIs?

STIs need a method of entry to pass an infection from one host to another. Condoms, when used correctly, form a physical barrier preventing entry. The pill gives **no barrier to entry**.

I have yet to find a (reputable) source which claims that the pill gives any protection for STIs.

On the other hand, the CDC by itself has several resources on condom effectiveness at preventing STIS:

- [Condom factsheet in brief](https://www.cdc.gov/condomeffectiveness/docs/condoms_and_stds.pdf) (PDF warning)
- [Condom factsheet](https://www.cdc.gov/condomeffectiveness/brief.html) (non-PDF) - has further sources at the bottom of the article
- [Condom Effectiveness](https://www.cdc.gov/condomeffectiveness/)

Comment: Good answer but not sure why you said you can't find a source claiming the pill protects against STIs. That's like saying you can't find a source claiming left is right or night is day. Just saying it that way implies it could be true, which is very misleading to someone who thinks it's possible.

Comment: @CareyGregory I take your point. I guess my thinking was: if I said "it gives no barrier" and left it at that it's an unreferenced assertion; by saying there are no sources to back it up makes it clear I have looked for references-- basically, *"it's not just me saying this"*! If you have a better way of phrasing it I am open to suggestions :)

Comment: (I also think in play here is me not wanting to dismiss something out-of-hand; there could be some *really subtle* effect on uterine secretions, membrane integrity or something that gives a 0.1%/0.5%/1%/etc 'protection'. Scientist at heart!)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but what is the "short-acting" and "long-active"?

Comment: @Blaszard - [Long-active and short-acting](https://www.mariestopes.org.uk/women/contraception/marie-stopes-contraception-care/what-types-contraception-are-there) contraception